# Photoshop CC Text Overrides Block Character Styles From Working

Tags: adobe-photoshop, character-styles

This is more of a description of a problem I'm having and not so much of a question. When I make a paragraph and format it to be the right size font and color, I can't highlight text and click on a character style without first clearing overrides. That would be fine, but it changed the font size, leading and kerning to some default size 12. So after clearing and clicking on the character style I have to edit the kerning, leading and font size. At that point it would be faster to highlight the text I want and manually set all the things I set up in my character style. Maybe I'm missing an easy work around. If anyone knows of a workaround I would appreciate it.

Comment: This seems like more of a tech support/ potential bug question to me. I would take this to the Adobe Forum for Photoshop and see what they have to say about it.

Comment: It might be helpful to keep a paragraph of sample text off your canvas that has the proper formatting. After editing and clearing styles on text you want you can eyedropper the sample text to restore styles.